# How to get value in input fill by another selection

Tags: forms, input, fill, autofill

i want to fill input box by selected option value: Selected option code here -

```
                   <div class="col-md-6">
                   <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Vendor</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <select class="form-control select2" name="vendor_id" id="vendor_id" style="width: 100%;">
                    <option >Select Vendor</option>
                    @foreach($vendor as $v)
                    @if ($v->status == 1)
                      <option value="{{$v->id}}">{{$v->name}} ({{$v->percent}}%)</option>  
                    @endif
                    @endforeach                        
                  </select>                        
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Selection image:
[See Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaHA8.png)

and input fill code:

```
<input id="percent" value="" type="hidden">
```

When Select option, active option percent value {{$v->percent}} need to auto fill input box.

Answer (score 0):

it's select2 .... try this :

```
$('#vendor_id').on('change', function (e) {
    var data = e.params.data;
    $("#percent).val(data);
});
```

Comment: not work that, i need {{$v->percent}} auto fill in input box when select a option